# Which related keywords API?

Tags: api, relationship, keyword

I am looking for recommendations for a related words/keywords API.

```
We have: "Mobile and Smartphones"
We need: "Android", "iPhone", "Apple", "Samsung" etc. 

We have: "Computers and Software"
We need: "Windows", "Microsoft", "Linux", "Laptop", "Tablet" etc.

We have: "Sports, Fitness, and Recreation"
We need: "Badminton", "Football", "Soccer", "Health"
```

We have about 1000 of these phrases that need to be queried. Are there any services that could provide related keywords like that? It's important that I don't get keywords that are too generic.

Is there a better place than Stack Overflow to ask this?

Comment: Any luck on this ? I am also looking for the same. I could see alchemyAPI and textRazor but they are better suited for analyzing text and extracting information from that. Could not fit them to the above use case

Comment: @mandeep_m91 No but we used google to find the top 20 websites for each of the terms and then use SEMrush to get organic search keywords for those 20 websites.